# Is there a problem with a loop for glm.nb model?

Tags: r, glm

I ran this code to perform an analysis to understand how the relationship between Acetic acid and the microbiome changes as different sets of the top 20 bacteria are considered. It uses shuffled data and Negative Binomial GLM to estimate correlations and R-squared values for each set of bacteria, aiming to find the best model fit for the data. The results are visualized in bar plots to determine how the model performance changes with the number of bacteria included in the analysis.

Here is my code:

```
# Negative Binomial Generalized Linear Model - Acetate
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Load microbiome data
microbe_data_acetate_network <- read.csv("ASV_acetate_network.csv", header = TRUE)

# Load metabolite data
metabolite_data_acetate_network <- read.csv("SCFA-acetate.csv", header = TRUE)

# Load microbe rank data
microbe_rank_acetate_network <- read.csv("Acetate_diffusion_microbe_15.csv")

# Sort bacteria by rank and select the top 20
top_20_bacteria <- head(microbe_rank_acetate_network$taxon, 20)

# Initialize empty vectors to store correlations and R-squared values
spearman_correlations <- numeric(20)
r_squared_values <- numeric(20)

# Number of shuffle iterations
num_iterations <- 100

# Loop through the top 20 bacteria sets
for (i in 1:20) {
  # Select the top i bacteria
  selected_bacteria <- top_20_bacteria[1:i]
  
  # Filter the microbiome data to include only the selected bacteria
  selected_columns <- c("SampleID", grep(paste(selected_bacteria, collapse = "|"), 
                                         colnames(microbe_data_acetate_network), value = TRUE))
  selected_microbe_data <- microbe_data_acetate_network[selected_columns]
  
  # Merge metabolite and selected microbiome data
  merged_data_network_acetate_network <- merge(metabolite_data_acetate_network, selected_microbe_data, by = "SampleID")
  
  # Set the dependent variable (Y) and independent variables (X)
  Y_network <- merged_data_network_acetate_network$Acetic.acid
  X_network <- merged_data_network_acetate_network[, -c(1, 2)]
  
  # Initialize vectors to store results from shuffled datasets
  shuffled_correlations <- numeric(num_iterations)
  shuffled_r_squared <- numeric(num_iterations)
  
  for (j in 1:num_iterations) {
    tryCatch({
      # Shuffle the data
      set.seed(j)  # Set a different seed for each shuffle
      shuffled_indices <- sample(nrow(merged_data_network_acetate_network))
      
      # Subset the shuffled data
      shuffled_data <- merged_data_network_acetate_network[shuffled_indices, ]
      
      # Split shuffled data into training and test sets (80:20 split)
      train_indices_network <- createDataPartition(Y_network, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
      X_train_network <- shuffled_data[train_indices_network, -c(1, 2)]
      Y_train_network <- Y_network[train_indices_network]
      X_test_network <- shuffled_data[-train_indices_network, -c(1, 2)]
      Y_test_network <- Y_network[-train_indices_network]
      
      # Combine the predictors and response variables into a single data frame
      train_data_network <- data.frame(Y = Y_train_network, X_train_network)
      
      # Define the control parameters for cross-validation
      control_network <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                      number = 10,
                                      repeats = 100,
                                      summaryFunction = defaultSummary)
      
      # Train the model using Negative Binomial GLM with repeated k-fold cross-validation
      model_network <- train(Y_train_network ~ .,
                             data = train_data_network,
                             method = "glm.nb",
                             trControl = control_network)
      
      # Predict the test data using the final model
      predictions <- predict(model_network$finalModel, newdata = data.frame(X_test_network))
      
      # Calculate the Spearman correlation and R-squared value for this shuffle
      spearman_correlation <- cor(Y_test_network, predictions, method = "spearman")
      linear_r_squared <- summary(lm(Y_test_network ~ predictions))$r.squared
      
      # Store the correlation and R-squared values for this shuffle
      shuffled_correlations[j] <- spearman_correlation
      shuffled_r_squared[j] <- linear_r_squared
    }, error = function(e) {
      # Handle any errors here, e.g., print an error message or take appropriate action
    })
  }
  
  # Store the best result from the shuffled datasets
  best_spearman <- max(shuffled_correlations)
  best_r_squared <- max(shuffled_r_squared)
  
  # Store the best result in the vectors
  spearman_correlations[i] <- best_spearman
  r_squared_values[i] <- best_r_squared
  
}

# Create bar plots for the best Spearman correlation and R-squared values
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))  # Set up a 2x1 grid for plots
barplot(spearman_correlations, main = "The Best Spearman Correlation Coefficient vs. Number of Microbes",
        xlab = "Number of Microbes", ylab = "Best Spearman Correlation")
barplot(r_squared_values, main = "The Best R-squared vs. Number of Microbes",
        xlab = "Number of Microbes", ylab = "Best R-squared")

# Reset the plotting layout
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

After I ran this, I found there are no values for Spearman correlation or R-squared stored. Is there a problem with a loop?

Thank you.